# Trace only class under test with rcov

Tags: ruby, tdd, rcov

I want to start `rcov` for a single test but the execution took several seconds/minutes since rcov seems to load the complete applications and starts to trace all source files. I'm only interested in the `rcov` report for the class under test. To improve the feedback time I want to exlcude all other files.

```
# run rcov/test for MyClass (my_class.rb)
rcov --text-coverage my_class_test.rb
```

The commandline offers me the `--exclude`/`--exclude-only` but I couldn't find a proper solution for my question.

How can I exlude all classes/files except my class under test (e.g. `my_class.rb`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the source code I found a solution.

```
rcov --include-file my_class.rb --exclude-only .+ my_class_test.rb
```

But `rcov` does collect all classes of the project before running the test. Maybe there is room for improvement.